# Можно ли пересмотреть изменение голосования?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, голосование

Можно ли оспорить то, что с меня сняли 45 репутации? Написано "голосование исправлено". Видимо один и тот же человек голосовал за мои вопросы. Прошу внимательнее проверить. Я вчера за один день задал 10 вопросов, можно видеть что на них много отвечали одни и те же люди, почему не могло быть что все эти вопросы понравились одному человеку? Скорее всего тому кто на них отвечал. И получилось что он много раз в течение короткого времени голосовал за мои вопросы. Можно еще проверить, вчера не давал ни одного ответа, так что это не могло быть в качестве благодарности за хороший ответ.

Comment: ну 45 - не 110 ) и "одним и тем же человеком" можете оказаться вы, поэтому система так себя и ведет; don't worry, be happy )

Comment: @ВОРОН, Обидно, 100% уверен что честно получил эти 45 (а это серьезный процент от моей репутации :))), а за свои вопросы вообще никогда не голосую, можно посмотреть сколько у меня с нулем голосов вопросов. То есть никогда не пересматривают снятие?

Comment: не знаю, вряд ли, я не обжаловал снятие, поэтому сказать не могу

Comment: @BOPOH: нет, за свои вопросы он не мог голосовать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мог, если бы еще кого-нить зарегистрировал. Т.е. тем аккаунтом происходила бы накрутка рейтинга теукщего аккаунта, система против этого и борется

Comment: @ВОРОН, а что, система знает только что голосовал один человек, но не знает кто этот человек? Если знает можно же посмотреть его профиль. Если там ни одного вопроса, ни одного ответа и только голоса за мои вопросы, тогда наверное я) Вчера несколько человек были очень активны на моих вопросах, отвечали на многие из них, спасибо им большое. Особенно один из них. Это же можно легко проверить. Думаю он и голосовал за 9 из 10 вопросов(так получается 45 баллов). У него довольно высокая репутация, много ответов, понятно же что это не я создал такого пользователя

Comment: не ко мне вопросы, я такую систему не писал, откаты проводят вроде как если за раз было дано много плюсов, а это уже подозрительно, а про рейтингового пользователя: а что если вы - не вы, а он? ) хочет кто-нибудь себе второй аккаунт иметь с нормальным рейтингом - вот и плюсует, системе-то какая разница какой у вас рейтинг, ей главное чтобы все как можно честнее было

Comment: @ВОРОН, а получилось как раз нечестно :) ладно, конечно, ничего страшного. Но пользуюсь случаем скажу, что почему бы системе более пристально это дело не отслеживать. Уверен, можно вычислить того кто мне плюсовал и посмотреть сколько у него ответов в моих вопросах. Если плюсы самому себе еще как то можно понять, то зачем мне отвечать то самому себе с разных аккаунтов?? :))

Answer (score 5):

Система снятия репутации как раз и предназначена для того, чтобы ваша репутация отражала общий вклад в сообщество, а не просто тот факт, что ваши вопросы понравились какому-то пользователю.

Первоначально система вводилась для предотвращения обратного явления — массового минусования. Представьте, что вы не понравились какому-то пользователю. И он активно минусует ваши вопросы. Т.е. как только вы вопрос задаете — на него летит автоминус, вне зависимости от качества вопроса. Было бы справедливо откатить такие минусы? — скорее всего да. Тогда и откатка плюсов справедлива — ведь для массового плюсования достаточно иметь всего 15 репутации.

45 репутации — это мало. Продолжайте задавать хорошие вопросы, и скоро вы про эти пару снятых плюсов и не вспомните :)

Comment: хорошо, понял, спасибо!)

Comment: скажите, а это вообще нормально, что я за всё время пребывания на stackoverflow дал всего 2 ответа, а в основном только задаю вопросы. Получается что я сообществу не особо много полезного сделал, а репутация уже 300

Comment: и еще интересует, может вы знаете.. Я вот слышал что в крупных компаниях когда кандидат приходит смотрят есть ли у него аккаунты на хабре, на SO(особенно на SO) и если есть, да еще с большой репутацией то это может оказаться плюсом. Интересно, правда ли это. Спрашиваю ни в коем случае не с целью накручивать репутацию, тем более что это видимо очень проблематично сделать :)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров да, вполне нормально. Хорошие вопросы приносят не меньше пользы, чем хорошие ответы. Насчёт аккаунтов - не уверен, но лично меня кандидат с высоким рейтингом на so впечатлил бы :)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Задавать качественные вопросы — это тоже полезное занятие. Многие отвечающие страдают, что мало хороших вопросов. :) Для регулярно задающих хорошие вопросы даже специальные значки добавили: Любознательный, Пытливый ум и Сократ. У вас есть некоторый перекос в сторону слишком широких вопросов, но в целом жить можно. / Что касается трудоустройства, то, насколько я слышал, если и обращают внимание на репу на СО, то скорее смотрят наполнение профиля, а не число, потому что репу зарабатывать можно очень разными способами.

Comment: @Discord, Спасибо, приму к сведению :) перекос наверное из-за того что в голове никак не сложится цельная картина, а пока она не сложилась тяжело задавать конкретные, узкие вопросы, хочется более широкого охвата. Универ я, к сожалению, выбрал экономический (ну, точнее прикладная информатика в экономике, но программированию почти не учат), среди знакомых программистов нет, вот и приходится все постигать самому. А в процессе постижения появляется очень много вопросов :)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: чтобы в голове сложилась цельная картина, читайте книги, например Thinking in Java. Ответы на SO вам не заменят книг.

Answer (score 2):

Система считает, что если один и тот же человек голосовал за вас пять раз и больше не голосовал (почти) ни за кого, то голосование не может быть честным по определению. :) Замечу, что пять голосов за одного пользователя — это ещё не повод для сброса голосов, нужны какие-то дополнительные условия, например, та же эксклюзивность — чтобы голоса в этот день были *только* за юзера. Ещё от репы голосующего зависит, кажется.

В целом, это не есть нормально, даже если голоса отданы без задних мыслей. Если позволить такие обоймы голосов, то репутация будет сильно зависеть от набегов случайных пользователей на популярные аккаунты. Зашёл кто-нибудь в профиль, прошёлся по 20 вашим самым популярным ответам — и вот уже максимум за день выбит. С одной стороны, всё в меру честно и даже приятно. С другой, остальным пользователям будет обидно, что другим такая халява достаётся.

В общем, забейте вы на эти 45 очков. Это вам сейчас кажется, что число большое, а вообще-то это не так много. ;)

Comment: ну да, пожалуй все правильно, спасибо :)